# Error al buscar línea mas grande de un archivo: tamaño 0 caracteres

Tags: java

Necesito saber cuantos caracteres tiene la linea mas grande de un fichero, al momento de imprimir me dice que son 0 caracteres y mi fichero tiene el siguiente contenido: 
adojodigj
adjiqoegjkpogrfxzs
cshfcjxz
xskehrysask
dwpodujjsoicxcm
asokjoijhdiclkmlslkjcklcml

```
package C4A2;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LineaLarga {


    public static void main(String args[]){

        try{
            FileReader fr=new FileReader("leelinea.txt");
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s;
            String s2="";
            while((s=br.readLine())!= null){
                System.out.println(s);

            }


            while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
                if(s.length()>s2.length()){
                    s2=s;
                }
            }
            br.close();

            System.out.println("La linea mas grande contiene "+s2.length()+" caracteres");
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fe){
            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado");
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero lees todo el archivo para imprimirlo y después vuelves a leerlo para calcular la longitud. Pero la cuestión es que en la primera parte YA HAS LLEGADO AL FINAL DEL ARCHIVO. Al seguir leyendo, br.readLine() siempre devuelve null y nunca llegas a entrar en el segundo bucle.

Lo más normal es hacer todo (imprimir, y calcular cual es la línea más larga) en el mismo bucle. Si lo quieres hacer en dos, entre los dos bucles tendrás que cerrar el archivo y volverlo a abrir para empezar a leerlo desde el principio.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice **@SJuan76**, primero lees todas las líneas del fichero y luego intentas leerlo de nuevo para calcular la longitud de las líneas pero ya está cerrado el fichero.

Una **propuesta** es incluir el segundo while dentro del primero, así matas dos pájaros de un tiro:

```
while((s=br.readLine())!= null){
    System.out.println(s);
    if(s.length()>=s2.length()){
        s2=s;
    }
}
```

PD: A ver si puedes ayudar en mi problema que puse en una pregunta del foro. @SJuan76